# Python: Unknown Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm stumped. I looked through my code a bunch of times and can't find out why I'm getting an invalid syntax for this bit of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
def nameReverse():

    name = str(input("Enter your full name: "))
    testName = name.split()

    if len(testName)>1:

    firstName=testName[0]
    lastName=testName[1]
    print (lastName,firstName)

def main():
    nameReverse()

main()
```

Comment: It seems you didn't intend 'nameReverse()' correctly.

Comment: nameReverse() is not correct and also always show the error that you are getting :)

Comment: The actual stack trace would be quite useful. This error is due to wrong indentation or mixing spaces and tabs.

Comment: @farbiondriven it's indented one tab in my shell, I don't know why it didn't copy over. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

If it is python 2.x you should use

```
name = str(raw_input("Enter your full name: "))
```

Full code:

```
def nameReverse():

    name = str(raw_input("Enter your full name: "))
    testName = name.split()

    if len(testName)>1:

        firstName=testName[0]
        lastName=testName[1]
        print (lastName,firstName)

def main():
    nameReverse()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The only error I got was an indentation error. This is python, so indentation is critical. Your `if` statement was improperly indented. Here is what you want:

```
def nameReverse():
    name = str(input("Enter your full name: "))
    testName = name.split()

    if len(testName)>1:
        firstName=testName[0]
        lastName=testName[1]
        print (lastName,firstName)

def main():
    nameReverse()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I copied this code into Python and am still getting a syntax error at 'def main():'

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax, the highlighted part is the 'def' before 'main'

Comment: So, you copied this code into a python file and ran it with `python my_file.py` and it didn't work?

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for the help! This is my first-semester coding so I'm still getting used to all of the rules and constants.

Comment: What was the problem?